# How to get around SQL Server Analysis Services 2 billion distinct value limitation on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, olap-cube

What is a best practice to get around SSAS 2 billion distinct value limitation on a column.  My data set grows by 2 billions rows every 10 month and one of the measures in the cube is a row count that runs on the PK. Because adding partitions does not help resolve the problem, would creating new  cubes with identical info be the right approach?

Comment: 2 billion columns or 2 billion rows? I think you are mixing them up.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2 billion distinct values on one column, so it is 2 billion rows

Comment: You're storing the lowest level detail in your cube, with no aggregation?

Comment: No, I am aggregating. I have a fact table and am measuring count of rows from source table that has more than 2 billion unique values

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365363.aspx 
Rows in a table: Unlimited
Note Caution: With the restriction that no single column in the table can have more than 1,999,999,997 distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to run the count on a column? This should only be necessary if you have duplicates in your table. Could you not just count rows? Then just omit the primary key column.

Comment: That makes sense. It might be that simple! Thanks.

Comment: What's important to note is that a Fact table does not need a PK. By omitting a PK I would have resolved my 2 billion unique values ceiling problem

Answer (score 0):

after almost 10 years, I also encountered such a mistake. It helped me at the beginning of the query to use TOPN(3000000000, table) and surprisingly it worked!